# Building a Cordova app (not PhoneGap) under OS X for iOS environment

Tags: ios, cordova

I can see that I have to do this commmand to compile within terminal

```
cordova build ios
```

And I want to find the isa file so I can upload it to the store.  Where is the isa file after I give the command `cordova build ios`?

The compiling is a success and I see two lines of

```
*** BUILD SUCCEEDED ***
```

on the terminal.

Or should I do it with "application loader"?

I know XCode is excellent but I prefer to do it with "application loader".